Создание картограммы при помощи R / как отредактировать размер текста и карты для лучшей видимости?

Я построил карту Республики Башкортостан / РФ, но не могу правильно настроить размер текста (названия регионов), а также не получается настроить размер карты (увеличить её) для лучшей видимости и удобочитаемости...
Карту взял с сайта GADM


Как можно заметить размер cex или же size начиная с 2 перекрывает названия других регионов, что касается размеров меньше, то его плохо видно...
Что мне делать в такой ситуации?

Как можно заметить размер cex или же size начиная с 2 перекрывает названия других регионов, что касается размеров меньше, то его плохо видно.
Что мне делать в такой ситуации?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.. p.s. я подправил форматирование вокруг картинок, вы уж сами разберитесь, какие там не нужны.
